# MongoDB, WriteConcern: need some clarification

Tags: java, mongodb

I need some help to clarify the concept of WriteConcern
I'm using MongoDb 4.0.2 (with a replicaset) and java-mongo-driver 3.8.1

I already added on mongo configuration the last default write concern with

```
{
    "w": "majority",
    "wtimeout": 5000
}
```

In code-side, when can I use the ack response from the database?
I found that the library, when you use delete or update, return an object of Result (as DeleteResult) that contain a function `wasAcknowledged()` for take the result of delete/update on the majority replica in the set.

But I'm not able to find a similar Result for all insert function. Someone could explain me how to use WriteConcern in order to avoid data loss?

**My goal is catch an Exception when insert/write/update on replica-set going in error**

Hope the question is clear, I'm waiting for your answer. Thanks

Just to know, is enough set this preferences on db, or I have to set the write-concern preferences also on my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch `MongoWriteConcernException`.  Below are the source codes and comments for `insertOne`.

```
/**
 * Inserts the provided document. If the document is missing an identifier, the driver should generate one.
 *
 * <p>Note: Supports retryable writes on MongoDB server versions 3.6 or higher when the retryWrites setting is enabled.</p>
 * @param document the document to insert
 * @throws com.mongodb.MongoWriteException        if the write failed due some other failure specific to the insert command
 * @throws com.mongodb.MongoWriteConcernException if the write failed due being unable to fulfil the write concern
 * @throws com.mongodb.MongoException             if the write failed due some other failure
 */
void insertOne(TDocument document);
```

Comment: Okay, I've already seen this docs, in this case my question is: why is not throwed on method signature? @simagix

Comment: Note that it is an uncheck method of an interface `public interface MongoCollection<TDocument>`.  You don't have to add the throws clause to the interface if it's a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: effectively is true, as user I would have found it useful. Btw, thank you!